# How do I configure my server to permit X11 Forwarding with applications which require `sudo`

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, x11

I can login to my server `ssh -X user@192.168.1.1` and I can run applications such as `gvim`.

However I cannot run superuser applications.

```
sudo gparted
Unit tmp.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.

(gpartedbin:4069): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:29:53.342: cannot open display: localhost:11.0
```

I couldn't find anything from a websearch or search of this website which seemed to be directly relevant.

Surely some sysadmin somewhere at some point in time needed to do something like partition a disk which required `sudo`?

My server runs Debian 10.

Answer (score 1):

You have to preserve the environment variables

- `XAUTHORITY` and
- `DISPLAY`

You need the `sudoers` directive `keep_env` for that. It can be used globally or for single commands (which may be safer).

Add this to `sudoers`:

```
Cmnd_Alias X_GPARTED = /path/to/gparted
Defaults!X_GPARTED env_keep += "XAUTHORITY DISPLAY"
```